# Python: Converting a None value from the print() function into a string

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with 'and' inserted before the last item.

For example, passing the list 'spam' which contains the values `['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']`, would return: `"apples, bananas, tofu, and cats"`.

I wrote the following code:

```
def thisIsIt(alist):
  alist.insert(-1, 'and')
  alist1 = alist[:-2]
  alist2 = alist[-2:]
  for item in alist1:
    print(item, end = ", ")

  for item in alist2:
    print(item, end = " ")
```

which does return: apples, bananas, tofu, and cats.
However it is printed as a Nonetype, instead of a string. How can I correct this please?

Comment: *However it is printed as a Nonetype, instead of a string* How do you know that?

Comment: I think you have what you print & what you return backwards; this function does not return anything, but certainly prints something.

Comment: May be you are looking for a function similar to [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/277017aea4cf72a1797102e6d129165181d04e17/django/utils/text.py#L233)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, if you want a different solution and want it to return a String you can use the power of [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in python:

```
def thisIsIt(alist):
  resultString = ", ".join(alist[:-2] + [" and ".join(alist[-2:])])
  return resultString

myList = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
myListAsString = thisIsIt(myList)
print(myListAsString)
#apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
list_sample = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

for i in range(0,len(list_sample)):
    if i < len(list_sample)-1 and i != len(list_sample)-2:
        print(list_sample[i],end = ", ")
    elif i == len(list_sample)-2:
        print(list_sample[i],end = " and ")
    else:
        print(list_sample[i])
```

**Output :**

```
apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried **KISS**. (Keep It Simple Stupid)

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats', 'oranges']

def newlist(x):
    myStr = ''    
    if len(x) != 0:
        for i in range(len(x)-1):
            myStr += str(x[i]+', ')
    return(myStr + 'and ' + x[-1]) 

newlist(spam)
```

I think for beginners like me try to keep things simple, guys!